# Vba code doesn't change the value of Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets on excel , first one with some rows and columns , an ActiveX control Button and checkbox  , when i click on this button i execute this code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Call do_OM

End Sub

Private Sub do_OM()

Dim Name_sheet As String

Dim row_se As Long

Dim Vl_1 As String

row_se = CheckBox1.TopLeftCell.Row

 Vl_1 = Range("D" & row_se)

 Name_sheet = ActiveSheet.Name

 Sheets("Or_Mission").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

 ActiveSheet.Name = "OM" & & Name_sheet

 Range("C11") = Vl_1

MsgBox Range("C11") & Vl_1

ActiveWorkbook.Save
                

End Sub
```

What i want is to copy the value of ( `Vl_1 = Range("D" & row_se)` ) that exists in first sheet TO the second sheet using   `Range("C11") = Vl_1`

The problem is The msgBox shows exactly the wanted result , But in the second sheet Range("C11") is empty !! i don't know what's happening , if any one can help

How can msgBox of Range("C11") that's in sheet 2 shows the value while in excel The cell is always empty ??

At the same time im using MsgBox becaus Debug.Print doesn't print anything ?? don't know why
Thank you :) .

Comment: Best to qualify the worksheet before every `Range` call.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand what do you mean ?

Comment: Ah i see, i tried this but nothing changed , i used to do the same why it's just weird right now , i don't understand why msg Box of Range("C11") shows the right value while it's empty in excel sheet

Comment: `MsgBox Range("C11") & Vl_1` ... because you're concatenating `V1_1`.

Comment: I tried MsgBox Range("C11") only it shows the value , this problem is happening with all ranges in sheet 2 , MsgBox shows there values while they'are emty in excel

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your revised attempt that qualified the `Worksheets(...)`.

Comment: i have a question, i wrote this simple code in Microsoft excel Object ( sheet 1) , can this be the problem ?

Comment: Ah... in that case `Range` refers to sheet1, but to be explicit you would add `Me`: `Me.Range("...")`. So if you want to refer to a different sheet than sheet 1, you would need to use `Worksheets`.

Comment: ah okey i'll try this way

Comment: If you don't qualify the worksheet, than the implicit qualifier is `Me`, i.e. the sheet with the module containing this code.

Comment: Finnaly !! Thank you so much it worked right now after adding Me for ranges of sheet 1 and Worksheets for ranges of sheet 2 !! Thank you again !!